# Buildfire: Theme is overwriting styling

Tags: styling, buildfire

I am trying to set the color of a  in the html of a widget index.html.
How can I set the color`<h2 style="color:{{x.titlecolor}}">` with out it getting over written by the theme's styling?

Answer (score 1):

You can disable theming in your plugin by adding the following tag to head of your index.html file, for your widget.

```
<meta name="buildfire" content="disableTheme=true">
```